# nested case when in python pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

There is a sql code with multiple nested case when statements as below:

```
select case when t1.marks is null and t1.country in ctry_list
then case when t1.class='maths' 
          then (select t2.marks*5 from table2 t2 where t2.class='algebra' 
                and t2.country=t1.country) end else t1.marks end as new_marks
from table1 t1
```

Aim is to convert this sql code to pandas syntax

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? By looking at your query I can tell that you can solve this by using simple filter and merge operations on 2 dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Suppose below 2 are your sample table definitions

```py
data_table1 = {
    'marks': [None, 90, 85, None, 75],
    'country': ['USA', 'USA', 'UK', 'Canada', 'UK'],
    'class': ['maths', 'science', 'maths', 'maths', 'science']
}
table1 = pd.DataFrame(data_table1)

data_table2 = {
    'marks': [80, 85, 90],
    'country': ['USA', 'UK', 'Canada'],
    'class': ['algebra', 'algebra', 'algebra']
}
table2 = pd.DataFrame(data_table2)
```

Considering below as a country list to filter

```py
country_list = ['USA', 'UK']
```

You can achieve the results by the following snippet,

```py
# Calculate new_marks based upon a few conditions
mask = (
    (table1['marks'].isnull()) 
    & (table1['country'].isin(country_list)) 
    & (table1['class'] == 'maths')
)

# Merge table1 and table2 on conditions to calculate new_marks
table1.loc[mask, 'new_marks'] = table1.merge(
    table2[table2['class'] == 'algebra'], 
    on=['country'], 
    how='left')['marks_y'] * 5
)

# Fill new_marks with original marks where conditions are not met
table1['new_marks'].fillna(table1['marks'], inplace=True)
```